# hcaptcha 'missing-input-response' problem

Tags: html, node.js

I'm looking for this fix like 7days. So problem is that i was working on node project all went good but there was problem which i trying to fix a 7days i was try all way Redelete files ask AI but all failure. Problem is with hcaptcha.com i was trying to put hcaptcha.com on my website for login when me enter or someone it should ask for captcha when someone click on button "login" but nothing. It's say Unknown Error and in my logs say
HCaptcha.com check failure: [ 'missing-input-response' ]. So i would ask if someone can help me i willing to send every code is requested from me.